# Using Selection sort within an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, selection-sort

I have a class called Person, where I have a constructor, getters, and setters for three variables: name, age, and height. I also have implemented a Selection sort method in this class to sort the ages of people. Then I have created an array with ten people and I have given them different names, ages, and heights, but I have not gotten to use the Selection sort method to sort the ages of people. I would like to know if you could help me to know what I am doing wrong and why I have not gotten to use the method within my array.

I would also like to know if there is a smarter (less manual) way to implement an array of the type I would like to (with name, age, and height), because I will add more people, like 20 people, and that is going to demand some extra work that I guess I could save with some better method. I know how to do it with an array list, but I would like to know with an array if that is possible, or reasonable.

```
//Class Person

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int height;
    private int age;

public void Person (String name, int height, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName (){
    return name;
}

public int getHeight (){
    return height;
}

public int getAge (){
    return age;
}

public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setHeight (int height) {
    this.height=height;
}

public void setAge (int age) {
    this.age=age;
}

public int[] selectionSort (int[] age){

    int i, j, minValue, minIndex, temp =0;

    for (i = 0; i<age.length; i++) {
        minValue = age[i];
        minIndex = i;

        for (j=i; j<age.length; j++) {

            if (age[i]<minValue){
                minValue = age [j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if (minValue<age[i]){
            temp=age[i];
            age[i]=age[minIndex];
            age[minIndex]=temp;
        }
    }
return age;
}
}

//Array implementation

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Person [] persons = new Person [3];

    persons [0] = new Person ();
    persons [0].setName("Josef");
    persons [0].setHeight(170);
    persons [0].setAge(30);

    persons [1] = new Person ();
    persons [1].setName("Marie");
    persons [1].setHeight(160);
    persons [1].setAge(35);

    persons [2] = new Person ();
    persons [2].setName("Karel");
    persons [2].setHeight(180);
    persons [2].setAge(40);

    for (int i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Jméno: " + persons[i].getName()+ ", věk: " + persons[i].getAge() + ", vyška: " + persons[i].getHeight());
    }

    //My main problem is here
    for (int i = 0; i<persons.length; i++){
        System.out.println(persons[i].selectionSort());
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Move sort method outside of person class, to main or some util class and use person age array as input...

Comment: According to the code you posted, method `selectionSort()` in class `Person` has a `int[]` parameter, but in method `main()`, you call method `selectionSort()` **without** any parameters.

Comment: This is another problem, I am not sure how to call the method with the parameter, when the "data type" of my array is the name of the class (Person). Should I just do this `selectionSort(age)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, you have to study it online and clear your concepts. However, I am going to explain a bit:

```
System.out.println(persons[i].selectionSort());
```

Now, you have created this method `selectionSort()` and you can use this on an object of type `Person` but it is expecting a parameter of type `int[]`, which you are not providing.

It is a logical error, `selectionSort` doesn't work like that you can't call this method on every index of array. Its his job to sort the array at once. So, you have to pass the whole `persons[]` array and the rest will be done by `selectionSort()`

```
public int[] selectionSort (int[] age)
```

You are using `int age[]`, you can't do this because you don't have an array of type `int`, what you have is array of type `Person` each object of type `Person` has an attribute `age` and you can access this by `dot operator`.

Working Code:

```
public class Person 
{
    public static Person [] persons = new Person [3];  // so that every method can access this array
    private String name;
    private int height;
    private int age;  

    public void Person (String name, int height, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName (){
        return name;
    }

    public int getHeight (){
        return height;
    }

    public int getAge (){
        return age;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHeight (int height) {
        this.height=height;
    }

    public void setAge (int age) {
        this.age=age;
    }

    public static void selectionSort(Person persons[])
    {
        int smallest;

        for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
        {
            smallest=i;
            for(int index = i+1; index<persons.length; index++)
                if(persons[index].age<persons[smallest].age)
                    smallest=index;

            swap(i,smallest);   
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int frst, int scnd)
    {
        Person temporary = persons[frst];
        persons[frst] = persons[scnd];
        persons[scnd] = temporary;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        persons [0] = new Person ();
        persons [0].setName("Josef");
        persons [0].setHeight(170);
        persons [0].setAge(35);

        persons [1] = new Person ();
        persons [1].setName("Marie");
        persons [1].setHeight(160);
        persons [1].setAge(31);

        persons [2] = new Person ();
        persons [2].setName("Karel");
        persons [2].setHeight(180);
        persons [2].setAge(40);

        for (int i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Jmeno: " + persons[i].getName()+ ", vek: " + persons[i].getAge() + ", vyska: " + persons[i].getHeight());
        }

        selectionSort(persons);
        for (int i = 0; i<persons.length; i++){
            System.out.println(persons[i].age);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I have merged code in same class `Person`, but you can divide them into `Main` and `Person` always. It is recommended that if you divide the code then include `selectionSort()` in `Main`.